# Remove K,V pairs with value 'NULL' from json object in query result

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

The following gives me a result : `{"a":null,"b":99.0,"c":null}`
I'd like to have `{"b":99.0}` as a result so I can use the result in a JSON patch. How can I achieve this with sqlite/json1?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     a REAL, b REAL, c REAL
);

INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) 
VALUES (1,2,3), (1,99,3);

SELECT json_object(
           'a', NULLIF(new.a, curr.a), 
           'b', NULLIF(new.b, curr.b),
           'c', NULLIF(new.c, curr.c)
       ) AS result
  FROM test curr
 INNER JOIN test new ON curr.id
 WHERE new.id = 2 AND curr.id = new.id -1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fiddling later:

```
SELECT json_group_object(key, value) 
  FROM json_each(json('{"a":null, "b":99.0, "c":null}')) AS result
 WHERE result.value IS NOT NULL;
```

results in `{"b":99.0}`

So the whole thing becomes something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     a REAL, 
     b REAL, 
     c REAL
);

INSERT INTO test(a,b,c) 
VALUES (1,2,3), (1,99,3), (2,99,4), (1,999,3);

WITH J(kv) AS (
  SELECT json_object(
           'a', NULLIF(new.a, curr.a), 
           'b', NULLIF(new.b, curr.b),
           'c', NULLIF(new.c, curr.c)
         )
    FROM test curr
   INNER JOIN test new ON curr.id
   WHERE new.id = 2 AND curr.id = new.id -1
)
SELECT json_group_object(key, value) AS result 
  FROM json_each((SELECT kv FROM J)) AS kv
 WHERE kv.value IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to remove NULLs from a json object is to apply it as json patch onto an empty json object:

```
select json_patch('{}','{"a":null,"b":99.0,"c":null}') ;
```

results in `{"b":99.0}`